# How to get static images from Django Backend to Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, django, django-staticfiles

The project has two independent repositories, one for the backend, and other admin(front-end). I have a folder with images in the backend project (static image files). Each image is associated with a name. Now when I click on a particular name in my admin side, I want a popup of the linked image from the Django backend.

Do I need to build some APIs in the backend to do this? Or Angular can load the static image files from the Django backend directly? What would be the optimal flow to build this functionality?